# How to get rid of "You have new mail." in zsh

Tags: terminal, zsh

I'm using zsh with prezto as my shell with iTerm as terminal app.

I always get the message "You have new mail" when opening a new prompt. I don't have any new mail in Mac Mail and I don't run a mail server.

How can I get rid of this message?

Thanks

Comment: You have mail in /var/mail - use the mail command to read

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It tells you that you have received some mails (for example, because of your configuration of cron).

The best way is to read this mail. Type `mail`: at least one mail should appear. You can read by typing its number ID. You can also directly delete it (or even multiple mails) by typing `d 1-1344` (`1-1344` being the range of your new mails' IDs). Leave `mail` with `x`.

Comment: You may need to use `q` instead of `x`, to save changes

Comment: You slipped in an extra `1` digit.

Answer (score 15):

Whether `zsh` checks for new mail can be adjusted through the `MAILCHECK` parameter as described in [zshparam(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshparam). It specifies the interval in seconds between checks for new mail, a zero turns off the checks completely. So just put this into your `zsh` configuration file:

```
# don't check for new mail
MAILCHECK=0
```

Comment: this doesn't work in `~/.zshrc` on mac OSX with `oh_my_zsh`. is there another zsh configuration file? is there a work around?

Comment: Very late reply, but in case others find this page: you could also try ~/.zshenv if it is not working in ~/.zshrc

Answer (score 10):

So apparently some program (probably my MAMP) put an email in

```
/var/mail/
```

Deleting this message did the trick...

Comment: ugh… I'd been seeing that in terminal for so long it felt like it was just its way of saying 'Hello". Nice find.

Comment: So you feel like trashing the contents of your mailbox is a good idea? Do you also do this in real live?

Comment: Well the mail in question was more a mistake by a local server. I am on Mac OS and my mails are stored somewhere else. So trashing this file was ok. If your actual mail is stored under /var/mail YOU SHOULD NEVER DO THAT...

Answer (score 9):

In case you want to check what those mails actually are before ignoring them, you can read the mails by:

```
mail
```

and read one the emails by entering a number, e.g.:

```
1
```

and if you have fixed the problem reported by the mails (in my case, the `cron` jobs are failing due to renaming a folder) and feel comfortable to delete all the mails:

```
delete *
```

then quit the program:

```
q
```

as shown in following screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unsetting (or even changing the value of) MAILCHECK didn't stop the message printed when I open a terminal tab/window. I eventually stumbled on an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/149284/860631) on superuser that enables me to still see this mail when it's convenient, but skip the constant nag message.

In short, create a `~/.forward` file and, on a single line, the path of a file you'd like to receive mail in. Later, you can still elect to read the mail with `mail -f <new_mail_file>`.

If you have more advanced needs, it [looks like](http://www.softpanorama.org/Mail/pipes_in_dot_forward_file.shtml#pipes) forward can also specify a script by setting the line to `|script_path` or `"|script_path args"`. I haven't tried this, but it should make it pretty simple to route messages based on the script that produced them, convert/compact them into a simple summary logline, etc.